# WPF Xaml StringFormat

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Boa tarde pessoal, estou com um problema um tanto quanto ridículo, mas não consigo encontrar a solução.

Estou tentando alguns `stringFormat` como `StringFormat={}{0:#,#.00}}` e `StringFormat=N2}`, além de `StringFormat='c'`, porém tirando o primeiro que não compila (não sei o por que) os outros inserem 2 casas decimais (valor + 00), porém eu gostaria que ele considerasse as últimas duas casas do valor como sendo os centavos.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Valor Fator" Binding="{Binding 
PendenciaValorFator, Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat=N2, 
UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsReadOnly="False">
```

Estou enviando um decimal com esse formato: 728001 e ele está mostrando 728.001,00, porém eu gostaria que mostrasse 7.280,01.

Adicionando, preciso que seja enviado um valor númerico para o grid caso contrário quando for fazer o "order" ele irá fazer por string assim, colocando em primeiro o valor 1.111,11 ao invés de 999,99.

Comment: Par mostrar como você quer a string tem de ser "7280.01"

Comment: Coloquei no banco de dados 7280,01 e 7280.01, o resultado foi 728.001,00

Comment: Qual é o tipo de `PendenciaValorFator`?

Comment: Estou fazendo o teste como decimal, pois quando eu estava utilizando como string ele estava ordenando como string, colocando 1.111,11 na frente de 999,99.

Comment: Não me expliquei bem no meu primeiro cometário. O que queria dizer é que para o valor ficar formatado assim:"7280.01", o valor de `PendenciaValorFator`(tipo decimal) tem de ter casas decimais: `PendenciaValorFator = 7280.01;`

Comment: Se jogar 728001 o WPF vai entender que é setecentos e vinte oito mil e um, e vai formatar para 728001,00 ou 728,001.00 de acordo com a cultura. Você precisa criar um Converter para personalizar isso;

Comment: @ramaral se quiser colocar como resposta, irei aceitar!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que a string resultante da formatação tenha as casas decimais como pretende é necessário que o valor de origem, neste caso `PendenciaValorFator`, represente esse valor com essas decimais.

Ou seja, para que o resultado seja `"7280.01"` é necessário que `PendenciaValorFator` seja igual a `7280.01` e não `728001`.